# Оптимизация алгоритма на Java

Tags: java, алгоритм

**Суть проблемы** Решаю задачи на Code wars, возникла проблема связанная со временем выполнения алгоритма, он привысил доступное значение времени (16000мс) и вот возникает вопрос, как мне оптимизировать мой код ибо другого алгоритма я даже представить не могу. Интересует решение именно написаное самостоятельно (типа велосипед изобрести), имеется в веду не используюя уже готовые для этого функции а написать свой алгоритм. Задача прилагается: [условие задачи на Code wars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ce399e0047a45001c853c2b/train/java)

> Пусть задан массив
>
> ```
> ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
> ```
>
> Он состоит из следующих частей
>
> ```
> ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
> ls = [1, 3, 6, 10]
> ls = [3, 6, 10]
> ls = [6, 10]
> ls = [10]
> ls = []
> ```
>
> Необходимо вернуть массив, состоящий из сумм элементов каждой части
>
> ```
> [20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]
> ```

**Мой алгоритм работающий больше 16000мс**

```
 int[] pairSums = new int[ls.length + 1];
     int sum;
     int length = ls.length;
     for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
       sum = 0; 
       for(int j = i; j < length; j++){
         if(ls[j] == 0){
           continue;
         }
         sum += ls[j];
       }
       pairSums[i] = sum;
     }
     pairSums[pairSums.length - 1] = 0;
     return pairSums;
```

В коде есть несколько не понятно зачем добавленых моментов, но уже на уровне бреда максимально пытался уменьшить количество итераций и прочего, не знаю буду ждать креативных ответов :)

Comment: @Эникейщик, как это перейдите по ссылке

Comment: Ответ уже есть, добавлю что у вас проверка if(ls[j] == 0){ continue; } совершенно бесполезна. Она не сокращает количество операций ни в одном случае, и увеличивает во всех.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем так сложно? Просто заполняйте массив `pairSums` с конца, прибавляя текущий элемент к последней вычисленной сумме

```
int[] pairSums = new int[ls.length + 1];
int sum = 0;
pairSums[ls.length] = sum;
for(int i = ls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  sum += ls[i];
  pairSums[i] = sum;
}
return pairSums;
```

> Completed in 11ms
> You have passed all of the tests! :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ, голова до такого моя не додумалась )